# SPARQL BIND IF bound Not Working As Expected

Tags: sparql

Given the following SPARQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?mainRestaurant ?p ?o WHERE {
  ?registeredRestaurant <http://testData.com/terms#RestaurantType> "Registered Restaurant" ;
     <http://testData.com/terms#city> <http://testData.com/city/london> .

  ?normalRestaurant <http://testData.com/terms#RestaurantType> "Restaurant" ;
     <http://testData.com/terms#city> <http://testData.com/city/london> .

  BIND(IF(bound(?registeredRestaurant), ?registeredRestaurant, ?normalRestaurant) as ?mainRestaurant )

  ?mainRestaurant ?p ?o. 
}
```

I would expect that if:

```
 ?registeredRestaurant <http://testData.com/terms#RestaurantType> "Registered Restaurant" ;
     <http://testData.com/terms#city> <http://testData.com/city/london>
```

has not returned anything then `?registeredRestaurant` would not be bound to anything and therefore in the following part of my SPARQL query:

```
BIND(IF(bound(?registeredRestaurant), ?registeredRestaurant, ?normalRestaurant) as ?mainRestaurant )
```

`?mainRestaurant` would bind to `?normalRestaurant` but the overall SPARQL query just doesn't return anything. However, when `?registeredRestaurant` does have triples associated to it, then the SPARQL query returns as expected.

I have managed to determine that it is the `bound(?registeredRestaurant)` that is the problem by replacing it with `true` and `false` and then `?mainRestaurant` is populated with `?registeredRestaurant` or `?normalRestaurant` respectively.

Have I misunderstood the use of `bound()`? If so, is there a function that fulfills what I am trying to do?

Comment: As written, your query uses regular `JOIN` operations between the statement patterns and these do not produce solutions with unbound variables. You need to use left join  - aka `OPTIONAL` to have solutions where some vars are unbound to which your filter with `IF(BOUND()` to be applied.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. If you add an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: instead of `IF(BOUND(...` you can also use `BIND(COLAESCE(?registeredRestaurant, ?normalRestaurant) AS ?mainRestaurant)`